# Connexion client with nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm new with nodeJs and I can't find a solution to my problem.I have a login interface I wan't after the connexion of 2 users an alert is displayed .My problem is the alert is displayed always before the connexion of the second user.
How can I make it appears after the login of the second user:
this is my client.js code:

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5050');
 $('#loginform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        socket.emit('login' , {
            username : $('#username').val(),
            mail     : $('#mail').val()

        })
    });
    socket.on('loged' , function(){

       $('#login').fadeOut();

});

    socket.on('newuser' , function(user){
        $('#users').append('<img src="' + user.avatar + '">');
    })
```

my code server.js

```
    var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var md5 = require('MD5');
var alert=require('alert-node');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
       });
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var users = {};
var i=0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket,user) {
    var me;
    console.log('new user is connected');


for (k in users) {

        socket.emit('newuser' , users[k]);
    }
socket.on('login' , function(user){

       me=user;
        me.id=user.mail.replace('@','-').replace('.','-');
        me.avatar = 'https://gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(user.mail) + '?s=50';
        socket.emit('loged');
        users[me.id] = me;
         io.sockets.emit('newuser', me);

});

}); 

server.listen(5050);
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any alerts on you code, so i assumed the following, you can check how many users are connected by `i++` or disconnected `i--` but you don't use it anywhere in your code, in this case i used an `Map` for storing users. Notice that if you make use of `alert-node` in your Node.js script it will simply use `console.log` if you include in your browser it will use plain `alert` so..

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const md5 = require('MD5');
const alert=require('alert-node');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
   });
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var users = new Map();

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket,user) {
    console.log('new user is connected');
    for (k in users) {
        socket.emit('newuser' , users[k]);
    }
    socket.on('login' , function(user){
        let me = user;
        me.id=user.mail.replace('@','-').replace('.','-');
        me.avatar = 'https://gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(me.mail) + '?s=50';
        users.set(me.id,me)
        io.sockets.emit('newuser', me);
        socket.emit('loged');
        if(users.size === 2){
            // notify that they are two users connected?
        }
    });

});

server.listen(5050);
```

Personally i would create an class that extended the EventEmitter and work with that it would be easier to maintain and so on.